# How to type a number into a text box and make it part of a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new here and I have a question: I'm building a page and I have a link with a number inside. Can I instead provide a text box that takes the number and inject it as a part of the link?

I'm using HTML and JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit and re write your question as best as possible? That way  someone can answer it.

Comment: English is obviously not Gil's first language, perhaps someone with high enough rep can clean up the question for them.

Comment: It's not that hard to understand. There is a text box, and the numeric value of that text box should be stored inside the href attribute of an anchor on the page.

Comment: I keep thinking It must be amazing to new users to see their question texts clarified and/or translated into better English right before their eyes. That's not a service you see often!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery solution:

```
$('#numberInput').keyup(function() {
    var n = parseInt(this.value, 10),
        href = 'http://www.foo.com/' + n + '/bar/';

    if ( !isNaN(n) ) {
        $('#link').attr('href', href).text(href);
    }
});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xs7Ag/

Comment: +1 Great example. Because the user with the question is new, it should be noted the jQuery library is needed to run your script with: http://jquery.com/  (just in case it's not immediately evident)

Comment: i dont know why but when i putting the code i'm always getting an error for $ chart,

help anyone ?

Comment: @Gil What does the error say exactly? In which browsers do you get this error?

Comment: nvm, i didnt know about the jquery file , i use it now and it all works, thanks

Comment: @Gil Sorry about that. I should have said that you have to include the jQuery script in your page.